# Comparing Time.now with model dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

my Project model has 2 datetime atttributes: start_date and end_date.
Now I want all projects where the current time is in between these dates.
I tried something like this with the start_date to start with:

```
@projects = Project.where(:start_date <= Time.now)
```

But this returns an error:

```
comparison of Symbol with Time failed
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unlike some ORMs, active record doesn't augment the symbol class with methods to allow expressions other than equality to be expressed in this way. You just have to do

```
Project.where('start_date <= ?', Time.now)
```

The squeal gem adds this sort of stuff and allows you to write

```
Project.where{start_date < Time.now}
```

Comment: OK, that works thanks! ANd combining it with end_date would be like this? ==> Project.where('start_date <= ? AND end_date >= ?', Time.now, Time.now)

Comment: You can either do that or chain a second call to `where`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this: `:start_date <= Time.now`. You're comparing a symbol and a date with the `<=` operator.

If you want to add a condition to your query, pass it as a string:

```
Project.where("start_date <= ?", Time.now);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, with a where clause comparing dates, you'll have to drop into SQL. Try something like this instead:

```
@projects = Project.where(['projects.start_date <= ?', Time.now])
```